# What is the purpose of defining an alias of the type of struct itself in it's own struct definition

Tags: c++, c++11, alias

What is the purpose of the alias definition of type aliasing struct type `__variant_idx_cookie` itself in following struct definition of `__variant_idx_cookie`?

`struct __variant_idx_cookie { using type = __variant_idx_cookie; };`

Comment: There's no obvious reason. What's the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably there will be a template of the form `template<typename T>` *...stuff involving* `typename T::type`*...*, which is expecting various classes with `type` member types.

I hope you are reading that from your implementation's source for the standard library, because the name `__variant_idx_cookie` is reserved for the implementation, because it has `__` at the start.

Comment: `__` **anywhere** in an identifier is reserved.